# Creating a circular linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I haven't worked with linked lists in a long time, and I can't figure out why this code fails. I'm trying to create a very simple circular linked list with exactly 5 nodes. I will never need to insert additional nodes nor delete existing ones.

I get a `'node' has no member named 'next'` error. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

```
typedef struct {
    char payload[1024];
    int x;
    node* next;
} node;

node* root_ptr;
node this_node; 

root_ptr = malloc(sizeof(node *));
root_ptr = &this_node; //keep a pointer to the root
int i;
for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
    node next_node;
    this_node.next = &next_node;
    this_node = next_node;
}
this_node.next = root_ptr;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
int main(){

    // create root and helper nodes
    node * root_ptr;
    node * this_node = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node)); 

    this_node->x = 0;

    root_ptr = this_node; //keep a pointer to the root
    int i;
    // create list
    for (i=1; i<5; i++) {
        node * next_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
        next_node->x = i;
        this_node->next = next_node;
        this_node = next_node;
    }
    // complete cycle
    this_node->next = root_ptr;

    this_node = root_ptr;
    // check
    for (i=0; i<5; i++){
        printf("%d\n", this_node->x);
        this_node=this_node->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

note that it's a generally bad idea to assign stack memory in a link list

Comment: That's pretty much how I solved it. Once I realized that I needed the 'node_t' part, then I was able to get the malloc's working. The only change to your answer that I would suggest is to change `this_node.next` to `this_node->next` since this_node is a pointer. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah it's too late (or early) here in Israel.

Edited.

Good night.

Comment: No worries. Get some sleep!

Answer (score 3):

Inside your struct member the `typedef` name is still unknow. So, should to give a name to your struct and then you can declare a identifier with it:

It will work:

```
typedef struct node_t {
    char payload[1024];
    int x;
    struct node_t* next;
} node;
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped. I think that I figured out the rest.

Answer (score 2):

First, `root_ptr = malloc(sizeof(node *));` is redundant.

Second `node next_node;` defines a local variable which will go out of scope after the `for` loop. You need to dynamically allocate memory for next_node.

Third, you have 6 nodes including the root, not 5.

Comment: It's perfectly fine if it goes out of scope. In fact, it's designed that way. All I need are the five nodes that know each other's memory addresses. Also, the root is a 'pointer' to a node, not a node, so I only have five nodes.

Comment: If it is out of scope, the memory is gone.

Comment: Yeah, I see your point. Although now I don't know what do to next.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do?

you need to use malloc in order to allocate memory on the heap which is freely available. You are currently using memory (in the for loop) which is considered free after the loop is done.

You can also use an array of nodes and link them if you want, but the popular method with linked lists is malloc which allocates heap memory.